# ¿Cómo concateno una lista de strings dentro de un ciclo for?

Tags: python

Antes que nada les quiero aclarar que soy primerizo en esto de la programación. He estado escribiendo un código para jugar al ahorcado y quedó listo.
Ahora mi problema es el siguiente; no sé cómo concatenar los elementos de una lista para utilizarlos en un ciclo for (no sé si sea la manera más conveniente de hacer mi merecido) para añadir un plus a mi juego: elegir si queremos jugar de la manera tradicional o **adivinando la palabra completa**, en esta segunda opción es cuando comienza mi problema.

```
        import random
        archivo=open('listapal.txt',encoding='utf-8-sig')
        leer=archivo.read()
        palabras=leer.split()
        palabra_secreta=random.choice(palabras)
        nombre=input('¡Bienvenido al juego del Ahorcado!, ¿Cómo te llamas?')
        tipo_juego=int(input('Ingresa (1) para jugar tradicional y (2) para tratar de adivinar la palabra completa'))
        print('Hola %s, comienza a adivinar :)' %nombre.title())

        letras_ingresadas=''
        oportunidades=6
        oportunidades_2=2
        while oportunidades and oportunidades_2 >0:
            errores_cometidos=0
            if tipo_juego==1:
                for letra in palabra_secreta:
                    if letra in letras_ingresadas:
                        print(letra)
                    else:
                        print('*')
                        errores_cometidos=errores_cometidos+1
                if errores_cometidos==0:
                    print(' era la palabra.\n¡Felicidades, %s, ganaste!'%nombre.title())
                    break
                letras_a_ingresar=input('Introduce una letra: ')
                letras_ingresadas=letras_a_ingresar+letras_ingresadas
                if letras_a_ingresar not in palabra_secreta:
                    oportunidades=oportunidades-1
                    print('Te equivocaste.\nTe quedan %s oportunidades!'%oportunidades)


            else:
                for letra in palabra_secreta: 
                    print('*')
                palabra_ingresada=input('Ingrese la palabra completa: ')
                if palabra_ingresada is palabra_secreta:
                    print(palabra_secreta)
                else:
                    errores_cometidos=errores_cometidos+1
                if errores_cometidos==0:
                    print(' era la palabra.\n¡Felicidades, %s, ganaste!'%nombre.title())
                    break
                if palabra_ingresada is not palabra_secreta:
                    oportunidades_2=oportunidades_2-1
                    print('Te equivocaste.\nTe quedan %s oportunidades!'%oportunidades_2)


        else:
            print('¡Perdiste!\nGracias por participar, %s.'%nombre.title())
```

Hasta antes del else dentro del while todo está perfecto.
A partir del else y al ejecutar el programa, si se decide ir por la opción 1 o 2 todo anda bien. Al elegir la 2 todo anda aparentemente bien, pero al ingresar la palabra correcta sigue contando errores y no muestra que se ha adivinado correctamente.

He intentado cosas como:

```
for letra in palabra_secreta:
  if ''.join(letra) is palabra_secreta:
    print(palabra_secreta)
  else:
    print('*')
```

y sigue dando el mismo resultado. ¿Existe alguna manera de concatenar los elementos de la palabra secreta para condicionarlos con la misma?. O, ¿cuál sería la mejor manera de lograr mi cometido?. Gracias por sus respuestas...

Comment: Hola Pedro, no uses `is` para comprobar si ambas cadenas son iguales, usa `if palabra_ingresada == palabra_secreta`.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ha funcionado, quién diría que era tan sencillo como eso. Aún me falta mucho por aprender...

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que usas `is` para comprobar si dos cadenas son iguales (mismo contendido) cuando debes usar el operador de igualdad:

```
 if palabra_ingresada == palabra_secreta
```

Explicación larga:

- `is` comprueba si dos identificadores apuntan al **mismo objeto** en memoria. Comprueba la identidad.
- Por contra `==` comprueba si ambos identificadores (apunten o no al mismo objeto) tienen el **mismo valor**. Comprueba la igualdad.

Puede parecer confuso, pero es fácil de entender, un ejemplo con un "objeto real", imagina que vas con un amigo por la calle y ve un coche pasar y te dice:

> ¡Mira un coche como el tuyo!

Esto lo entendemos como que ha visto un coche con los mismos atributos que tuyo, el mismo color, marca, etc . Pues el amigo a usado el operador `==` al comparar ambos coches, el coche puede o no ser el tuyo.

Ahora bien si te dice:

> ¡Mira tu coche!

Entonces no está diciendo que ha visto un coche como el tuyo, sino que ha visto tu coche. A usado el operador `is` para comparar ambos coches y le ha dado `True` (se deduce que por lógica `==` también dará `True`), lo cual si te puede ocasionar cierta intranquilidad...

En Python hay una pequeña excepción, por ejemplo nos podemos encontrar con esto:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 5
>>> a is b
True

>>> a = 1111
>>> b = 1111
>>> a is b
False

>>> a = "a"
>>> b = "a"
>>> a is b
True
```

¿Qué está pasando aquí? Según lo dicho antes, `a` y `b` son dos objetos distintos y por tanto siempre debería dar `False` al comparar con `is`... Cierto, esto se debe a un efecto secundario de una medida tomada por el intérprete en aras de la optimización. Por ejemplo, almacena de forma preventiva enteros pequeños (menores a 255) en forma de `singleton`. Otra cosa que se suele hacer es usar tablas hash internamente para optimizar la comparación de literales de cadena, estas optimizaciones hacen que eventualmente `is` apunte al mismo objeto, pero no significa que se esté usando correctamente cuando queremos saber si dos identificadores apuntan a objetos con el mismo valor a no ser que sea una especificación del lenguaje y no optimizaciones internas, dependientes de la implementación.

Por lo tanto, por regla general usar `is` para saber si dos identificadores apuntan al mismo objeto y `==` si tienen el mismo valor:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = a  # No se copia el objeto, solo se hace que b apunte al mismo objeto que a
>>> a is b
True

>>> b += 5 #Como int es inmutable esto crea un nuevo objeto
>>> a += 5
>>> a is b
False

>>> a == b
True
```

Hay una excepción a la que ya hemos hecho referencia, para cualquier objeto singleton se debe usar `is`, ver [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations). Un caso muy común es ver si un objeto es `None` o no. En este caso la forma recomendada es siempre:

```
foo is None
foo is not None
```

no

```
foo == None
foo != None
```

`None` es también un singleton (dicho de forma poco ortodoxa, el intérprete se asegura de que existe un solo objeto `None` en memoria y todos los identificadores apuntan a él) y la comparación es mucho más rápida vía `is`.